# Make a public class only extensible within an assembly?

Tags: c#, clr, access-modifiers, sealed

Is something like this possible in C#? What about CLR in general?

```
public sealed-outside class MySample
{
}
```

Comment: Simple answer: no. What are you trying to achieve that would lead you to want to do that? I suspect a public interface and internal classes would fit your needs,

Comment: @DavidArno This is a general question. My specific situation is a base non-abstract custom attribute that I would like to protect from being extended outside of the framework. It's not critical, I just wanted to know if there is a reason not to have this possibility in the language.

Comment: You are probably looking for [AttributeUsage] with *Inherited* set to false.

Comment: Add an abstract internal method.

Comment: @HansPassant Attribute *application* being inheritable has nothing to do with attribute *definition* being inheritable.

Comment: Thanks for down-voting without explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Only if you declare all constructors internal. Then only classes within the same assembly will be able to call a base class constructor which is required for inheritance. You may need some public static factory methods if others need to be able to create an instance.

If you want to be pedantic, this only prevents inheritance at the language level, not the CLR level. You could still technically create an inheriting class by declaring some mutually recursive constructors. Jon Skeet [demonstrated](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/10/23/violating-the-smart-enum-pattern-in-c/) this in an example.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Unfortunately it's just a workaround. E.g. you cannot use a factory to instantiate custom attributes.